# Eclipse + CDT: How to batch build several build configurations

Tags: eclipse, build-process, eclipse-cdt

I have an eclipse CDT project that builds static and shared libraries.  I have created several build configurations for them.

I want to know if there is any way to do a batch build i.e. build all configurations at once with single operation.  I tried "Build All" (ctrl+B) but it seems to be building only the current configuration (just that it applies "all" as the target for the current configuration).

One of the earlier posts suggest making use of CMake(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5204180/how-to-build-several-configurations-at-once-with-cmake) .

Is this the way, or is there any other alternative without getting into CMake.

regards,
Ravi

Answer (score 2):

If you have CDT installed, then there is also a launch configuration type called [**Launch group**](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/reference/cdt_u_run_dbg_launch_group.htm). You can create one of that to list all your other already configured launch configurations and to execute one after the other. Make sure to set the post build action in the list dialog to "wait until terminate".

Answer (score 0):

put all your projects into a tree (symlinks), e.g. my/Projects and run a headless build (ref http://gnuarmeclipse.livius.net/blog/headless-builds/)

eclipse -application org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.headlessbuild -importAll my/Projects -cleanBuild all -nosplash -data ./eclipse_ws_dir --launcher.suppressErrors -vmargs -Xmx7g