# Using CMake to generate multiple Code Composer build configurations

Tags: cmake, code-composer

My goal is to use a script/CMake to create a "Debug" build configuration and a "Release" build configuration that can be switched between within Code Composer Studio's UI (using the "Build Configuration -> Set Active..." option).

Currently,

1. A script is ran that runs CMake with desired commands (toolchain, etc).  A Code Composer Studio project is generated (as described in CMakeLists.txt)
2. CCS project is imported into CCS

The problem is this only generates a "Debug" build configuration.  Is it possible to add a command to CMakeLists.txt, or to cmake command line, or even ccs command line that allows multiple build configurations to be generated?

The only difference between the two will basically be defining NDEBUG, and possibly changing optimization level.

Comment: Did you look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5204180/how-to-build-several-configurations-at-once-with-cmake/11473277#11473277?

Comment: @user3288829 seems like that link suggests two separate CMake command line options.  Wouldn't that result in two separate Code Composer project files?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean for the link to point to that answer specifically (the accepted answer is actually much better). I've never used code composer, only Visual Studio and QtCreator. With both of those, you can switch back and forth between Debug and Release versions without needing to reload/switch projects. Using separate out of source directories does result in 2 sets of build files, which is the recommended practice so you don't have to rebuild your entire project every time you switch between Debug and Release.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this same question...then realized I am the one who originally asked this ~4 years ago!  Anyways, I found a way to do this:

Using Code Composer, create the build configuration(s) as you want them to behave.  When done, copy the .cproject file to a cproject.in "template".  CMake will use this template to generate an identical .cproject for any future cmake builds.  Make sure to replace any hardcoded values (ex: project name) with proper cmake variables.

For me, my CMakeLists.txt called `configure_file(path/to/cproject.in ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/.cproject @ONLY)`.

Also be sure to delete your CMakeCache and CMakeFiles if they already exist...I believe those were preventing me from seeing the resulting change.

Comment: would you mind to post your cmakelists.txt which creates a CCS Project? This is something I am looking for