# Cross compile multiple targets - distinct target name per platform?

Tags: cmake, cross-compiling

I run a shell script to `cmake` and then `make` for each platform (Linux, Win, etc.), in sequence, the platforms being supplied as toolchain files.

It appears that I need multiple target names in order for CMake to generate a distinct makefile per platform. What is the correct / canon way to go about this?

Please comment if any further information or build file contents are needed. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to build several configurations at once with CMake?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5204180/how-to-build-several-configurations-at-once-with-cmake)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @DevSolar for pointing out elsewhere that I need separate build folders to generate each platform's makefiles into.